# How does SQL Server generate values in an identity column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, identity-column

My question is if I have two batch inserts into one table in parallel, how does SQL Server create identity values?

I mean, if in one session I insert multiple rows (Row1-Row2-Row3) and simultaneously another session inserts multiple rows (Row4-Row5-Row6) at the same time, the result would be like this?

```
Row1
Row2
Row3
Row4
Row5
Row6
```

or maybe something like this?

```
Row1
Row6
Row3
Row5
Row4
Row2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making the common fallacy of assuming an order in the table. Tables have no order. Only results have order, which is undetermined unless an explicit ORDER BY is specified.

You may ask a different question: how is the identity generated value assigned in case of concurrent inserts? The answer is simple: **it doesn't matter**. And if you make any assumption about the order then your code is broken. Same goes for gaps. Your application should work even if the identities generated are completely random, and correctly written application *will* work if the identity is completely random. Use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to retrieve the last inserted identity. Better still, use the [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause of `INSERT`, it works for multi-row inserts too.

For the record: the identities are generated in the order on which operations acquire access to the [log stream](http://rusanu.com/2012/01/17/what-is-an-lsn-log-sequence-number/).

Comment: thanks for replay.I used SCOPE_IDENTITY() but i want to know could I sure that in a batch insert my previes Identity is SCOPE_IDENTITY()-1 or not?

Comment: Is a bad assumption. As I say, use OUTPUT clause for multi-row inserts.