# Can a record with a higher IDENTITY value be inserted before one with a lower IDENTITY value in SQL Server with large number of user?

Tags: sql-server

Let us assume that the SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 with many many CPUs is at the default transaction isolation level. A table `t1` has an `IDENTITY` column as the primary key and the insert statements leave it to the SQL Server to provide a value for the `IDENTITY` column. A user `A` issues an insert `i1` for `t1` while another user `B` issues an insert `i2` for `t1` near simultaneously or a  'jiffy' later than User `A`.

Based on the documentation that I have read so far, it is impossible to say which of the records, `i1` or `i2`,  will receive a lower IDENTITY value or be committed first. The only thing that is guaranteed is that it will be unique. I have read [How does SQL Server generate values in an identity column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577411/how-does-sql-server-generate-values-in-an-identity-column) as well as  http://rusanu.com/2012/01/17/what-is-an-lsn-log-sequence-number/ and have a follow-up question but I would like to give some context first.

I am reviewing a `FOR INSERT` trigger which is assuming order based on primary key value which is IDENTITY. I want to prove that in some situations `i2` can get inserted ahead of `i1` but just do not know how to do so, short of examining the data pages and luck. Appreciate if some can help me prove this, either through documentation or otherwise.  And please no "IDENTITY only guarantees uniqueness" OR "records in a table do not signify any order"  kind of responses. I already know that.

I need help in proving and/or disproving that a higher IDENTITY value can be inserted before a lower one in a high concurrency environment either through documentation or test cases. My peers are a tough bunch :)

Comment: To the person who voted down the question,  I have clearly stated the research that was done and what I am looking for. Please do not arbitrarily vote down without providing a reason.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Here's my repro:

```
use tempdb;
go
create table identity_test (id int identity, rv rowversion);
go
```

Then, I used SQLQueryStress to throw 20 threads at it, each running 1000 iterations of:

```
insert into identity_test default values;
```

Once that was done, I ran the following code to see which rows are "out of order"

```
with cte as (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (order by id) as a,
        row_number() over (order by rv) as b
    from identity_test
)
select *
from cte
where a <> b;
```

On my machine, that query came back with 173 rows.

Comment: cool. It took me a few seconds to figure out where you going with the timestamp column :)

Answer (score 1):

"Ahead of" is a slippery concept in relational databases, as you know.
If you want to show that inserts can complete out-of-order wrt the primary key, it should be as simple as opening two tabs in SSMS and executing

```
begin tran
insert into ...
```

in one tab, then

```
insert into ....
```

in the second tab, then

```
commit
```

in the first tab.  The trigger should see the two inserted rows in commit order but not in primary key order.  IDENTITY values are allocated in a strict order, but that order may be completely different than commit order, and must be treated as arbitrary from the point of view of user code (and nearly all system code too).

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by the "trigger should see the two inserted" ? ?

Comment: You said there is a `for insert` trigger.  I meant that the trigger should be called with the second inserted row before the row with the lower IDENTITY value.

Comment: Here is what I did DROP TABLE t1 
GO
CREATE TABLE t1 ( c1 INT IDENTITY , c2 INT)
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX i1 ON t1(c1)

go
CREATE TRIGGER t1_instead_of_trigger ON t1 FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 'inserted table', * FROM inserted
END
GO

Comment: What I wanted to say was that the FOR triggers fire as soon as the INSERT  is executed irrespective of whether the COMMIT is issued or not. Each  FOR INSERT trigger will see its own row in  the virtual/logical table  inserted  and not the row from the other INSERT statement.  
But I see your point. The tab in SSMS which commit first makes it record  accessible to the outside world. So the higher IDENTITY value row can be seen first if it is committed first and the one with the lower IDENTITY value later. I will go ahead and  mark you response as an accepted answer.